# DocuSign Default Print Destination deployment

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, configuration-files, docusignapi, silent-installer

I am hoping someone can help me with a deployment of DocuSign. I am trying to deploy out the DocuSign driver silently to machines, but I need to have the machines default print destination changed from DocuSign Web to DocuSign Web NA2.

I would like to do so in a Transform but I do not see any options for this in the msi. Also I was wondering if maybe there was a config file that stores this information but I couldn't find such a file.

Can someone please help me with this?

Regards,

Dustin

Answer (score 0):

The information is stored in the registry, not a config file. The Print Driver always would use www in the initial authentication call. I suspect this question was asked when it was still using legacy auth. this is not relavant anymore. The url is determined after the user logs in.

https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/print-driver-quick-start-v3-x